# Statistics about your bibtex database

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Does somebody know how can you do some data mining of your Bibtex database? For example, some statistics about the number of papers per journal, author or year; stuff like that. Is there a tool or a website available?

Comment: slightly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43066

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of such a tool, but it should be possible to process BibTeX data in statistical software (such as R) or even in Excel.

The [bibtex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibtex) package on CRAN can parse BibTeX files. Converting to a data frame should be possible on an attribute-by-attribute basis. Then you can analyze whatever you want. See also [this related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765493/how-do-i-reference-specific-tags-in-the-bibentry-class-using-the-or-conv).

```
> rref <- read.bib()
> rref
R Development Core Team (2009). _R: A Language and Environment for
Statistical Computing_. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna,
Austria. ISBN 3-900051-07-0, <URL: http://www.R-project.org>.
> str(rref)
List of 1
 $ :Class 'bibentry'  hidden list of 1
  ..$ :List of 7
  .. ..$ title       : chr "R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing"
  .. ..$ author      :Class 'person'  hidden list of 1
  .. .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. .. ..$ given  : chr "R Development Core Team"
  .. .. .. ..$ family : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ role   : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ email  : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ comment: NULL
  .. ..$ organization: chr "R Foundation for Statistical Computing"
  .. ..$ address     : chr "Vienna, Austria"
  .. ..$ year        : chr "2009"
  .. ..$ note        : chr "{ISBN} 3-900051-07-0"
  .. ..$ url         : chr "http://www.R-project.org"
  .. ..- attr(*, "bibtype")= chr "Manual"
  .. ..- attr(*, "key")= chr "R"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "bibentry"
 - attr(*, "strings")= Named chr(0) 
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
> rref$url
[1] "http://www.R-project.org"
```

If you prefer Excel, you might want to [convert your bib file to XML](http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/) first. I haven't tried that, though.

Answer (score 5):

This question is about [bibliometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliometrics).

**[bibliometrix](https://bibliometrix.org)** is an R package that incorporates several methods for such analysis. From their [introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibliometrix/vignettes/bibliometrix-vignette.html):

> **bibliometrix** package provides a set of tools for quantitative research in bibliometrics and scientometrics.
>
> Bibliometrics turns the main tool of science, quantitative analysis,
> on itself. Essentially, bibliometrics is the application of
> quantitative analysis and statistics to publications such as journal
> articles and their accompanying citation counts. Quantitative
> evaluation of publication and citation data is now used in almost all
> scientific fields to evaluate growth, maturity, leading authors,
> conceptual and intellectual maps, trends of a scientific community.
>
> Bibliometrics is also used in research performance evaluation,
> especially in university and government labs, and also by
> policymakers, research directors and administrators, information
> specialists and librarians, and scholars themselves.
>
> **bibliometrix** supports scholars in three key phases of analysis:
>
> - Data importing and conversion to R format;
> - Bibliometric analysis of a publication dataset;
> - Building matrices for co-citation, coupling, collaboration, and
>   co-word analysis. Matrices are the input data for performing network
>   analysis, multiple correspondence analysis, and any other data
>   reduction techniques.

## Installation

```r
install.packages(“bibliometrix”, dependencies=TRUE)
```

## Example

Taken from the vignette:

```
file <- "https://www.bibliometrix.org/datasets/savedrecs.bib"

M <- convert2df(file = file, dbsource = "isi", format = "bibtex")

results <- biblioAnalysis(M, sep = ";")

S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
```

This yields the information that OP asked and more:

> For example, some statistics about the number of papers per journal,

```
## Most Relevant Sources
## 
##                                                            Sources        Articles
## 1  SCIENTOMETRICS                                                               49
## 2  JOURNAL OF THE AMERICAN SOCIETY FOR INFORMATION SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY       14
## 3  JOURNAL OF THE AMERICAN SOCIETY FOR INFORMATION SCIENCE                       8
## 4  JOURNAL OF DOCUMENTATION                                                      6
## 5  JOURNAL OF INFORMATION SCIENCE                                                6
## 6  JOURNAL OF INFORMETRICS                                                       6
## 7  BRITISH JOURNAL OF ANAESTHESIA                                                5
## 8  LIBRI                                                                         5
## 9  SOCIAL WORK IN HEALTH CARE                                                    5
## 10 TECHNOLOGICAL FORECASTING AND SOCIAL CHANGE                                   5
```

Note that this is only displaying the top 10 journals, as defined by the `k` argument in the call to `summary()`. Similarly, only the top 10 authors are listed below.

> author

```
## Most Productive Authors
## 
##    Authors        Articles Authors        Articles Fractionalized
## 1     BORNMANN L         8     BORNMANN L                    4.67
## 2     KOSTOFF RN         8     WHITE HD                      3.50
## 3     MARX W             6     MARX W                        3.17
## 4     HUMENIK JA         5     ATKINSON R                    3.00
## 5     ABRAMO G           4     BROADUS RN                    3.00
## 6     D'ANGELO CA        4     CRONIN B                      3.00
## 7     GARG KC            4     BORGMAN CL                    2.50
## 8     GLANZEL W          4     MCCAIN KW                     2.50
## 9     WHITE HD           4     PERITZ BC                     2.50
## 10    ATKINSON R         3     KOSTOFF RN                    2.10
```

> or year

```
## Annual Scientific Production
## 
##  Year    Articles
##     1985        4
##     1986        3
##     1987        6
##     1988        7
##     1989        8
##     1990        6
##     1991        7
##     1992        6
##     1993        5
##     1994        7
##     1995        1
##     1996        8
##     1997        4
##     1998        5
##     1999        2
##     2000        7
##     2001        8
##     2002        5
##     2003        1
##     2004        3
##     2005       12
##     2006        5
##     2007        5
##     2008        8
##     2009       14
##     2010       17
##     2011       20
##     2012       25
##     2013       21
##     2014       29
##     2015       32
## 
## Annual Percentage Growth Rate 7.177346
```

## Caveat

This package assumes the `.bib` file (or other format) comes from a specified source: the `dbsource` argument in the call to `convert2df()`. If you already have an existing bib file from somewhere else, some analysis might not work well. From their [FAQ](https://bibliometrix.org/faq.html):

> **Q5 - I want to load a bibtex file created by a reference manager software but when I run the function convert2df it returns an error:**
>
> ```
> Error in seq.default(iStart, iStop) : 'from' must be a finite number
> ```
>
> The problem is the data format.
>
> Unfortunately, bibtex is not a proper standardized format, so it could
> change when created from different sources.
>
> Bibliometrix/biblioshiny need a bibtex file formatted exactly as
> exported by WoS or Scopus and with the full set of mandatory metadata
> (authors' name, affiliations, references, etc.). If not, it will not
> work.

I use [Mendeley](https://blog.mendeley.com/2011/10/25/howto-use-mendeley-to-create-citations-using-latex-and-bibtex/) to generate my bib files. I tried the example above with a few different bib files, and it was able to generate similar outputs, even though it throws a warning:

```
> bib <- '/path/to/my/bibfile.bib'
> bibdf <- convert2df(file = bib, dbsource = 'isi', format = 'bibtex')

Converting your isi collection into a bibliographic dataframe


Warning:
In your file, some mandatory metadata are missing. Bibliometrix functions may not work properly!

Please, take a look at the vignettes:
- 'Data Importing and Converting' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibliometrix/vignettes/Data-Importing-and-Converting.html)
- 'A brief introduction to bibliometrix' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibliometrix/vignettes/bibliometrix-vignette.html)


Missing fields:  ID C1 CRDone!
```

I would also recommend going through the *[Data Importing and Converting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibliometrix/vignettes/Data-Importing-and-Converting.html)* vignette in the warning message.