# Generate Reference Statistics

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically generate statistics about the references used within a document.

For example, to generate a histogram showing the number of references by year, that were cited within the document. Or, a graph showing the number of references by publication type (journal, conference, online).

This is similar, in a way, to [Statistics about your bibtex database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79142/statistics-about-your-bibtex-database), but I don't want to look at the entire BibTeX database, only what's used by the paper. And then, I want to use that data to generate a few plots.

My first thought was to write a script that parses the .bbl file, and generates the LaTeX code to create the plot.

However, I'm hoping that something like this already exists, maybe as an extension to BibTeX?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of parsing the `.bbl`, I think it would be easier to parse the `.aux` file for `\citation` commands, and pass those keys to something like [bibtexparser](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for that suggestion - I didn't realise the .aux file had the citation keys too. Will give that a try.

Comment: This question becomes a duplicate of the question linked by OP, considering that it only requires one extra step of generating a bib file containing the used references. For example, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41823/45342) that uses `bibexport`.