# Reference diagram from bibtex entries

Tags: bibtex, diagrams

When tracing article reference it is useful to create a diagram than show when an article reference another article. Does latex/bibtex support creation of such diagrams?

It will also be handy if the edges between the nodes can be decorated with additional information.

**Update**

File test.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}       
\begin{document}
\cite{Cirstea2007,Clarke1996,Clarke2003}    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibtex file:

```
@Article{Cirstea2007,
  Title                    = {title1},
  Author                   = {auth1},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Number                   = {10 SPEC. ISS.},
  Pages                    = {39--56},
  Volume                   = {174}
}
@Article{Clarke2003,
  Title                    = {title2},
  Author                   = {auth2},
  Journal                  = {J. Acm},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Xref                     = {Cirstea2007}
}
@Article{Clarke1996,
  Title                    = {title3},
  Author                   = {auth3},
  Year                     = {1996},
  Xdata                    = {43434},
  Xref                     = {Clarke2003}
}
```

Running the commands

```
latex test.tex
biber --output-format=dot test
dot -Tps test.dot  -o file.ps
```

A node is created for each entry with the text the citation key and the type of bibtex entry. The xref field create and arrow between the nodes: [image].

Changes that are still needed:

- add data to the arrow.
- each arrow from a node must support a different text value

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show, what you try so far? Or provide sketch of diagram? Is this some kind of tree with `\cite{...}` in nodes? Sorry, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Related, I think: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43066/tool-to-visualize-connections-between-bibtex-entries

Comment: In JabRef, we started to work on it: https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/2041. For very old versions of JabRef, there is the [PRRV plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jabrefprrvp/).

Comment: @ koppor from which version of JabRef will support the graphical representation?